# Install Local Plugin

Tags: typescript, command-line-interface, oclif

I generated a multi-command CLI using `npx oclif multi mynewcli`. I'm trying to install the default plugin created using `npx oclif plugin mynewplugin` as referenced [here](https://oclif.io/docs/plugins). I don't know see any documentation on how to actually do that though. Is there documentation I'm missing? How does the CLI know where to look for included plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have executed the two commands `npx oclif multi mynewcli` and `npx oclif plugin mynewplugin` is some directory for example in this case the `projects` directory, your directories will be structured like this

```
projects
|--- mynewcli
|--- mynewplugin
```

`cd` into the `mynewcli` project and

1. install the plugins installer with `npm i @oclif/plugin-plugins --save`
2. add this plugin into `package.json` in `oclif.plugins` array

   ```
   {
     "name": "mynewcli",
     "version": "0.0.0",
     // ...
     "oclif": {
        "plugins": [
            "@oclif/plugin-help", 
            "@oclif/plugin-plugins" // <== in here
        ]
     }
   }
   ```
3. run `./bin/run plugins:link ../mynewplugin` to link the plugin into your main project
4. run `./bin/run plugins` you will see your `mynewplugin` was added into your project

Answer (score 0):

In the link you supplied, it says where it knows where to look:

> Plugins can have commands or hooks just like a CLI. To add a plugin such as the not-found plugin plugin, first add it to your CLI with yarn add @oclif/plugin-not-found, then add the following to your package.json:
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "mycli",
>   "version": "0.0.0",
>   // ...
>   "oclif": {
>     "plugins": [
>       "@oclif/plugin-help",
>       "@oclif/plugin-not-found"
>     ]
>   }
> }
> ```